# Does SocketChannel.close() close the socket also?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, channel, socketchannel

I have a server program that needs to close any connections that remain when the server is shutting down. I know I need to call `SocketChannel.close()`. My question is if I also need to close the Socket associated with the `SocketChannel` or if `SocketChannel.close()` does that automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`SocketChannel.close()` should close the Socket. However, there have been some bugs around this issue (should have been solved a long time ago). https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4960962. Another situation that can cause problems: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6179351

Comment: The bug you now cite shows 'Resolved date: 2005-04-16'. If you've been having difficulties in this area, it is almost certainly because of the delayed close referred to in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it closes the socket. What else would it be for? The only exception is when the channel is registered with a Selector, when the actual close is deferred to the next select operation.